# Android push notification not getting registration id

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working on android push notification.I have created app on Google api console:

Also provide all permissions but still i am getting empty registration id.

**Here is my code:**

```
public void registerGCMNotifications(){
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "sender_id");//sender id
            Constants.REGISTRATION_ID = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        } else {
            System.out.println(regId);
        }
    }
```

This code return empty registrationId.

**Here is code for GCMIntentService:**

```
package com.interactive.pushnotification;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.interactiveapp.R;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.interactiveapp.Constants;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("sender_id");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
        Constants.REGISTRATION_ID=registrationId;
        System.out.println("ID: "+registrationId);
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        String message = arg1.getStringExtra("message");
        //displayNotification(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void displayNotification(String message)
    {
        //int count=Constant.pushNotificationsCount++;
        // this
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Get Device Date Time...
        Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a");
        String Strtdates = sdf.format(cl.getTime());

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
        Context context = getApplicationContext();     
        CharSequence contentTitle = "";  

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GCMIntentService.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "H",0);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, message, contentIntent);

        // and this
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        //System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: wait for some time......

Comment: Hi I have done with the problem. The problem was I din't put GCMIntentService in app main package.Now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` will return an empty registration ID the first time you run your app. `GCMRegistrar.register(this, "sender_id")` is asynchronous. Its result will be returned by `onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId)`, so if `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` returns an empty reg ID, expect to receive the reg ID from `onRegistered`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Eran but i have run my app many times but i am not getting registrationId via GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this) or in onRegisterd().

Comment: One more thing my projectId from google console is of 11 characters.And i found some other app having 12 characters long.